# ngDialog won't work with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ngDialog, https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#api

this is in my controller:

```
$scope.clickToOpen= function(){     
             ngDialog.open({
                    template:
                   '<button ng-click=savePost()> + Save</button>'  ,
                    plain: true,
                    className: 'ngdialog-theme-default'
                })
    }
```

and HTML is

```
 <button class="ion-android-more-horizontal" ng-click="clickToOpen()"></button>
```

the words 'save' is supposed to call the savePost function but it's not working

Comment: you should write `ng-click="savePost()">`

Comment: I tried that, no luck

Comment: Where is your `savePost` function?

Comment: in the same page, I just wrote it on it's on in the controlelr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your modal is not the ng-click, but the savePost function that is undefined inside the scope of your modal.

After looking at source code, it doesn't seem to have a way to share a function between a controller displaying the modal, and the modal itself.

What you need to do is to add a controller to your modal, and add there your modal logic :

```
$scope.clickToOpen= function(){     
         ngDialog.open({
                template:
               '<button ng-click=savePost()> + Save</button>'  ,
                plain: true,
                className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
                controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
                    $scope.savePost = function(){
                        alert("this one can be triggered by your template");
                    };
                }]
         });
}
```